# Can I fix photos with corrupt jpeg data?

Tags: jpeg, corruption

My phone (android, fwiw) takes pictures that are corrupted. I'm not sure why or how it is doing this, but it seems to prevent me from uploading the photos to some services. If I move the photos to my computer and open them in GIMP I see a warning message:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 1130 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

The error doesn't prevent me from viewing or editing the photos, but I'm wondering if there's some way to set up a batch process that would fix this problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's hard to tell without an image to try it on, but I would think ImageMagick would rewrite your images properly without the superfluous data. If you are on Linux it is probably installed, look for a program called `convert` and/or `mogrify` which belong to ImageMagick, else you can install it from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org).

Then you want a command that does nothing too drastic to your image, so something like this should be pretty harmless:

```
mogrify -set comment 'Extraneous bytes removed' *.jpg
```

Back up your files first though, and test before applying to thousands of images!

Comment: I had no idea I could set the comment with `mogrify` -- I might not have dug out `exiftool` if I'd known. But this works.

Comment: I got exactly the above-posted error message when trying to mogrify jpeg images obtained with a Canon Pixma scanner. So, your solution in this case does not seem to work...

Comment: @Mark, I must apologize, my previous comment was incomplete and unclear. What really happens is that when I mogrify one of the JPEGs in question, the image does get re-written in a 'clean' state. In addition, Mogrify returns a WARNING and keeps the original in the form of `myimage.jpg~`. I am using ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 on OSX.

Comment: `mogrify` will output some warning message about corrupt jepg image, but the original image have already been transformed to a clean sate. `mogrify` is helpful~

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem that the jpg file ended prematurely and mogrify wouldn't resize my images. My solution to this problem was to convert the images to png and back to jpg. This fixed the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

mogrify -format png *.jpg
rm *.jpg
mogrify -format jpg *.png
rm *.png
```

There might be a quality loss due to compression artifacts, but for my purpose this was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I was building an image classification model: I retrained the model (written in Tensorflow) using lots of images as input.

After some investigation, I found the error are caused by the image editing(crop and rotate). As the EXIF info still keep the original dimension, it doesn't match the latest dimension after editing. Fix is very easy, we can use `mogrify` of `imagick` to delete the outdated EXIF info.

`mogrify <file name>`

or

`mogrify -strip <file name>`