# .net Read Image: throw 'Parameter is not valid' in all ways but the solution exists

Tags: .net, bitmap

I have a function that reads a .jpg image and inserts it into a drawing.bitmap() to be able to edit it.
This feature has already edited thousands of images, but today it cannot read a specific image.
Initially it worked like this:

```
Using OriginalBmp = New Drawing.Bitmap(imgPath)
```

But only with this image, on this line of code, it raised the exception "Parameter is not valid"
So I looked for the solution in StackOverflow. There are many questions like mine, but they all have a solution that doesn't work for me.
I tried with:

```
    Using ms = New IO.MemoryStream
        Using source = New IO.FileStream(imgPath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Read)

            source.CopyTo(ms)
            ms.Position = 0
            ms.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

            Using OriginalBmp = New Drawing.Bitmap(ms) '<-- The exception is here
```

Or

```
    Using ms = New IO.MemoryStream
        Using source = New IO.FileStream(originalImg, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Read)

            Dim fileData(source.Length) As Byte

            source.Read(fileData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(source.Length))

                Dim td = ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(Drawing.Bitmap))

                Dim bmp = td.ConvertFrom(fileData) '<-- The exception is here
```

Or

```
    Using ms = New IO.MemoryStream
        Using source = New IO.FileStream(imgPath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Read)

            Dim fileData(source.Length) As Byte

            source.Read(fileData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(source.Length))
            Dim imgc As Drawing.Image

            Using ms32 = New IO.MemoryStream(fileData)

                ms32.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

                imgc = Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms32, True, False)
```

and I don't know how many other variations.

So I thought that the file was corrupt, in fact PhotoShop does not open it but only says "An error has occurred in the program"
However, if I open it with Google Chrome I see it.
I also tried to convert it with the website https://convertio.co and it converts it perfectly and the result is readable by any software.

In conclusion, there is something wrong with this image, but someone can open it like Google Chorme does, so this file can be read, the solution exists, but what is the solution?
Some idea?
Thank you

Comment: Evidently there is an issue with the file that some software is intelligent enough to correct/work around that others are not, there is no real answer to your question as it depends on the specific issue with this particular file.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, I would like to find this extra intelligence in my code. They are files that users upload from smartphones. I can't know what's coming. How do I figure out what's wrong with that file?

Comment: If the load fails you could try passing the file to a 3rd party utility such as imagemagick - E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805500/can-i-fix-photos-with-corrupt-jpeg-data

Comment: @AlexK. I tried imagemagick and solved the problem. Thanks for the help. I'd like to understand why I couldn't succeed with drawing.image, but there's so much more to do.